# Tree-Form of math formula (as a dot string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, sympy

I have the formula

a * b * cos( c * x ) + b

Is there the possibility to create a tree structure of the formula like in Mathematica (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/GraphUtilities/ref/ExpressionTreePlot.html)

for this formula, e.g. in numpy, sympy or even tensorflow?

---

Edit

With the help of the comments, I found, that one can plot it with like it is said under the first image in 
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html
using graphviz, but I don't understand, how.

Comment: You can try to use ```dotprint``` from SymPy. See https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/tutorial/manipulation.html or https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.5/modules/printing.html#sympy.printing.dot.dotprint

Comment: In Tensorflow, you can get a graph, which shows sequence of Operations, but not in a Tree form, for a Math Formula.

Comment: I am interested in plotting a tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, we can use sympy to generate the tree and [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) to render it. Below is the code to generate the digraph data and render it into a pdf. Note that in order to use Graphviz you need to install the Graphviz executables as well as installing through pip. Hope that helps!

```
from sympy import symbols, cos, dotprint
from graphviz import Source

a, b, c, x= symbols('a b c x')
expr = a * b * cos( c * x ) + b

src = Source(dotprint(expr))

src.render('output.gv', view=True)
```

[image]